# Ionic 2 app: remember user on the device

Tags: authentication, ionic2, remember-me

I have an Ionic App and I'd like to put a "Remember me" checkbox in the login page, so that once the user has logged in he'll be logged in forever (unless he logouts), even if he close and re-opens the application, just as the Facebook app does.
Is there a way to do that in Ionic 2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use localstorage to save some data for your own verification/logic handling.It's html5 supported and easy to use. The downside would be it won't be secure and it might be erased by system when there's low memory or clearing of cache.

HTML(Upon button press, but u can set it to your own preference):

```
<button secondary (click)="addLocalStorage()">Done</button>
```

In your controller:

```
import {Storage, LocalStorage} from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(navController, local) {
    this.navController = navController;
    this.local = new Storage(LocalStorage);
}
addLocalStorage(){
    this.local.set("didTutorial","true");
    //set the doneTutorial to be true
}
```

Explanation: 
At the constructor , we create an new localstorage object called 'local'.
To call it, we use 'this.local' and 'set' is the method to store it.

> Set(Key,Value)

In the example code above, i use 'didTutorial' as the key and 'true' as the value.

To retrieve it, you can retrieve it at this page or at any other page.
Just remember to import Storage and LocalStorage and declare a new localstorage object in the constructor.(same as above)

The code to retrieve is :

```
var value = localStorage.getItem('didTutorial');
```

> getitem(Key,Value)

Comment: You talk about its downside, isn't this the right way to do it? How do professional apps like Facebook do it?

Comment: @MicheleStieven , If you want to store user credentials , then securestorage(android) and keychain(ios) could be a possible alternative. There are plugins and libraries for that. But for simple things like remember me, you can use local storage like the example above.

Comment: @Gene why is it not possible to import Storage and LocalStorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use storage and sqlStorage to save user data. And then check it for saved user.

Refer :-
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/12/use-sqlite-in-ionic-2-instead-of-local-storage/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

localStorage works fine but I confirm the drawbacks that @Gene talks about. It is not reliable, especially on iPhones that do not have much free storage

I use ionic 1 so I cannot try this solution, but you might want to check this out : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/
; could be more reliable!